# if condition statment trigerred without condition being met for python

Tags: python, if-statement, data-structures

I'm solving a simple DSA problem and seem to grasp a general way to solve the question where Given an integer array called nums, I would move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.

For example, nums = [0,1,0,3,12]
Then the expected output would be. [1,3,12,0,0]

My approach was as below.

```
class Solution:
    def moveZeroes(self, nums: List[int]) -> None:
        count = 0
        while count < len(nums):
            if len(nums[count+1:]) == count:
                return nums
            elif nums[count] == 0:
                nums.pop(nums[count])
                nums.append(0)
            else:
                count += 1
            print(nums)
```

I would expect this to work in my mind, but the output is not what I expected because stdout shows as

```
[1, 0, 3, 12, 0] 
[1, 0, 3, 12, 0]
[0, 3, 12, 0, 0] 
[0, 3, 12, 0, 0]
```

Now I understand why the firsto two prints show as such, because 0 was identifed in the first loop and popped
However I do not understand why in the third and forth iteration, the result shows as [0,3,12,0,0].
The if-conditiona says if nums[count]==0, then nums.pop[nums[count]].
How is the pop and append triggered when the condition is not met?
Am I missing something here?

Comment: `nums.pop(0)` is not what you meant to call.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified in few lines:

```
def ceros_array(ar):
  '''Given and array of integer return zeros at end of array'''
  zeros = ar.count(0) # count zeros in array
  new_array = [x for x in ar if x !=0]  # new array with elements different that zero
  for i in range(zeros):  # cycle for zeros removed 
    new_array.append(0) # insert 0 at end of new array
  return new_array
```

I tested with these arrays:

```
>>> ceros_array([1, 0, 3, 12, 0])
[1, 3, 12, 0, 0]
>>> ceros_array([0, 0, 3, 12, 0])
[3, 12, 0, 0, 0]
>>> ceros_array([0, 0, 3, 0, 0])
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> ceros_array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> ceros_array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I love the list comprehension, it inspired [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75423066/246801), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [dannisis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75418386/246801):

```py
def shift1(nums: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    """Push all zeros in nums to the back (right) of the list."""

    # Keep only non-zeroes
    new_nums = [x for x in nums if x != 0]

    # Append the correct number of zeroes
    new_nums += [0] * nums.count(0)

    return new_nums


for nums in [
    [1, 0, 3, 12, 0],
    [0, 0, 3, 12, 0],
    [0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]:
    print(shift1(nums))
```

```py
[1, 3, 12, 0, 0]
[3, 12, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Here's a more general, albeit less performant, solution:

```py
def shift2(nums: list[int]):
    _len = len(nums)

    shift_ct = 0
    for i in range(_len):
        if nums[i] == 0:
            shift_ct += 1
            continue
        else:
            nums[i - shift_ct] = nums[i]

    # "Back fill" end w/any zeroes
    i = _len - shift_ct
    while i < _len:
        nums[i] = 0
        i += 1
```

This mutates the list you pass in:

```py
Nums = list[int]  # input to function
Want = list[int]  # what we expect in return
test_cases: list[tuple[Nums, Want]] = [
    ([0, 1], [1, 0]),
    ([0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]),
    ([0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0]),
    ([0, 1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0, 0]),
    ([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]),
]


def test_shift2():
    for nums, want in test_cases:
        got = nums[:]  # make copy to keep "input" separate from "result" in print-out, if test fails
        shift2(got)
        if got != want:
            print(f"shift2({nums}) = {got}; want {want}")
```

I've run a number of timeit tests and profiled both, and I believe shift1 is slightly faster because even though it has two function calls (1 for the list comprehension, 1 for count()), it just has less lines to execute; shift2 only has the one function call (len()), but far more lines for the interpreter to step through.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful about changing structure of iterable objects WHILE iterating through them. Think about what you are doing. On your first loop, you hit 0 when i = 1, you pop that out and append it to the end. So now, all the elements from that point are shuffled up to an index that is one lower. The 2nd 0 was initially at index 2 but is shuffled up to index 1. You then ADD 1 to your index, meaning the next element is skipped and not processed.

Your best solution is to is to append non-zero elements to a second list and then fill with zeros:

```
def moveZeroes(nums) -> None:
    new_list = []
    zero_count = 0
    for i in nums:
        if i > 0:
            new_list.append(i)
        else:
            zero_count += 1
    new_list += [0] * zero_count
    print(new_list)

moveZeroes([0, 1, 0, 3, 12])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and this works. (note that I used pop(count), not pop(nums[count]):
NOTE: After posting this answer, I noticed that it would fail if the initial list (my_numbers) starts with more than one zero. A quick and dirty fix for this would be to just call moveZeroes(my_numbers) twice.

```
def moveZeroes(nums):  
   count = 0  
   while count < len(nums):  
      if nums[count] == 0:  
        nums.pop(count)  
        nums.append(0)  
        count += 1  
      else:  
        count += 1  

my_numbers = [0,1,0,2,12,0,4]  

moveZeroes(my_numbers)  
moveZeroes(my_numbers)  # added as temporary fix for leading multiple zeroes 

print(my_numbers)  #prints [1,2,12,4,0,0,0]
```